# Namespaced models don't work with polymorphism and I need a workaround

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-3.1, polymorphic-associations

Polymorphic relationships don't work when the models are namespaced in rails 3.1. Here is an example:

```
class Accounting::Request::Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :accounting_request, as: :requestable
end

class Accounting::Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :requestable, polymorphic: true
end


cr = Accounting::Request::Check.create!()
cr.create_accounting_request
```

Results in:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Accounting::Request::Check::AccountingRequest
```

My question is, how can I work around this for the time being before we migrate to rails 5?

[One solution](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15811) I found was to add class_name: '::ClassName' but this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, rails does support polymorphism on namespaced models...

Here is the revised code that makes it work:

```
class Accounting::Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :requestable, polymorphic: true
end

class Accounting::CheckRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :accounting_request, as: :requestable, class_name: 'Accounting::Request'
end
```

`class_name` needs to be on the '-able' model, and needs to fully specify the class that contains `belongs_to`.

Also not that I'm using `has_one` here instead of `has_many`.